# Adobe AIR iOS - File.applicationStorageDirectory resolves to a different path at each launch

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, adobe, storage

I am saving a file in `File.applicationStorageDirectory`. It saves correctly, but at a second launch of the same app it is not loaded because `File.applicationStorageDirectory` points to a different folder.

Here are some examples:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EBF46358-3A82-45C8-A971-7656674543AE/Library/Application Support/com.royalatlantisapp/Local Store/

/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/09B41C51-CB5C-4FC6-BF34-CE42E2100241/Library/Application Support/com.royalatlantisapp/Local Store/

/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/ABD1C5F4-231C-4C9C-AD42-E426EF1B281E/Library/Application Support/com.royalatlantisapp/Local Store/
```

As you can see, at each launch of the app, a different folder is targeted.

Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: Are you recompiling between every launch?

Comment: Nope, I do write, then relaunch the same app. Does it change folder at each recompile?

Comment: Only if you've changed the id in the manifest, but the part that would change would be  `com.royalatlantisapp` - Your are running this right off the device itself?

Comment: Yep, the folder changed at each recompile. But actually I was using a nativePath instead of url to load file with a URLLoader, therefore it didn't work. (I use a complex Pre-Loading system, it makes it more streamlined to use a URLLoader). I wrote an answer in case others may do the same mistake.

Comment: You should update your question to show that you are using a URLLoader, as most people when using AIR will use FileStream.  Otherwise your own answer is a bit out of context.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I was loading data with a URLLoader, and I didn't grab path from the "url" property. Therefore, the app couldn't find folder at relaunch.

```
var f:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("myFile.xml");
var resultUrl:String = f.url; // This works to load with a URLLoader
var resultPath:String = f.nativePath; // This works to load with a FileStream operation
```